# Using **qualitative** and **quantitative** in the context of singular values in SVD

Tags: self-learning, article-writing

I am dealing with **singular value decomposition** of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}^{}\mathbf{\Sigma^{}} \mathbf{V}^{T}=\sum_{i=1}^{rank(\mathbf{A})}\sigma_i^{}\mathbf{u}_i^{}\mathbf{v}_i^{T}
\end{equation}

1. If $rank(\mathbf{A})=1$, we say $\mathbf{A}$ is **separable**.Period.
2. Consider another situation where $rank(\mathbf{A})=k>1$ but $\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_1}\leq\epsilon<<1\quad\forall\quad2\leq i\leq k$. In this case we would be inclined to say that $\mathbf{A}$ is **nearly separable**.

I am trying to use the following two terms: **qualitative** and **quantitative** to express this idea.

**My question is:** would it be correct to say that in (1) $\mathbf{A}$ is quantitatively separable whereas in (2) $\mathbf{A}$ is qualitatively separable

Comment: is there any mathematical definition oh "qualitative" and "quantitative" in the context of SVDs or linear algebra ?

Comment: I couldnt find one. But, in general, I feel that counting number of non-zero singular values to determine matrix rank is a very constraint way of looking at matrix rank. Their relative sizes should also play some part